# "Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==)" at particular line of perl script reported

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl scripting and one section of script it is looking for any AIX users that have a value of maxage=0

Here is body of the script.

```
$msg = "No violations";
$violations = "";
foreach my $user (@if_password_must_expire_users) {
        $i++ while (exists $pass_file[$i] && $pass_file[$i] !~ /$user:\s*/);
        my $id_found=1 if (exists $pass_file[$i]);
        $i++ while (exists $pass_file[$i] && $pass_file[$i] !~ /password\s*=/ && $id_found);
        if ($id_found) {
                if ($pass_file[$i] =~ /\*\s*$/) {
                        my $maxage_check=`lssec -f /etc/security/user -s $user -a maxage`;
                        my ($maxage) = ( $maxage_check =~ /[^=]+\s*([0-9]+)/ );
                        if ($maxage == 0) {
                                $violations .= $user."; ";
                                $msg = "Violations: ";
                        }
                }
        }
}
write_result($section,$msg);
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;` to get critical information and help avoiding simple mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant section of code is this:

```
my $maxage_check=`lssec -f /etc/security/user -s $user -a maxage`;
my ($maxage) = ( $maxage_check =~ /[^=]+\s*([0-9]+)/ );
if ($maxage == 0) {
  ...
}
```

The first line runs the external program `lssec` to get information about a particular user and stores the output from that command in `$maxage_check`.

The second line attempts to extract the actual maxage information out of the output from the external command and stores that value in `$maxage`.

The third line checks to see if the value stored in `$maxage` is zero.

But the warning you're seeing says that when you examine the value in `$maxage`, on the third line, that value is undefined (or, in Perl terms, `undef`). That would happen if the extraction on your second line of code didn't extract the value successfully. And that means your regular expression didn't match the data in `$maxage_check`.

The best way to investigate this further is to display the value of `$maxage_check` in the cases where the regex doesn't work.

Something like this might work:

```
my $maxage_check=`lssec -f /etc/security/user -s $user -a maxage`;
my ($maxage) = ( $maxage_check =~ /[^=]+\s*([0-9]+)/ );
if (defined $maxage) {
  if ($maxage == 0) {
    ...
  }
} else {
  warn "Cannot extract maxage successfully\n";
  warn "Input string: $maxage_check";
}
```

That will show you what the problematic command output is and from there you can work on fixing your regex so it matches correctly.

**Update:** We don't all work on AIX so we don't have a copy of `lssec` easily available in order to check what its output looks like. It would have been really helpful if you could have included examples in your question.

But it might be helpful to tell you what your current regex is trying to match:

- One or more characters that aren't equals signs, followed by...
- Zero or more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs), followed by...
- One or more digits (which you capture and store in `$maxage`)